# Can anyone help in Java Program Regarding String method

Tags: java, string, methods

Can anyone tell me how to debug this program. I have encountered an error using string method.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class StringUser{
public void show();
{

System.out.print("\nYou Entered: "+a);
}
public static void main(String args[])
{
Scanner obj=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter a String: ");

StringUser c=new StringUser();
String a=obj.nextLine();
c.show();
}}
```

Comment: This doesn't compile, you have declared **a** inside the main and you are trying to use it inside show, add a string as a parameter to show.

Answer (score 1):

Your `a` variable is local to the main method. If you want to access it in another method, you can pass it to that method :

```
public void show(String a) // also note that you mistakenly had a semi colon here
{  
    System.out.print("\nYou Entered: "+a);
}

public static void main(String args[])
{
    Scanner obj=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a String: ");

    StringUser c=new StringUser();
    String a=obj.nextLine();
    c.show(a);
}
```